# Pivot convert row to columns sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below. I need to Convert the rows in to columns. 
I know I could get this by union the select 5 times. I'm looking for advice on how to do this using pivot

```
ID    NAME   TAG    TAG_1   TAG_2   TAG_3   TAG_4  LOCATION
10    test   abc    abc_1   abc_2   abc_3   abc_4  china

ID    NAME    TAG        LOCATION
10    test    abc        china
10    test    abc_1      china
10    test    abc_2      china
10    test    abc_3      china
10    test    abc_4      china

with t as (
 select ID, name, tag,location from table_one
 )
 select * from t
 unpivot (
 value for tag in (tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4
 )
```

I tried using the above unpivot, I am getting invalid identifier ORA-00904 error for the column names (tag_1,tag_2). What is wrong in the statement.

Comment: what is your RDBMS? oracle? mysql? postgre? sybase?

Comment: RDBMS is oracle

Comment: Hope below answer works in oracle as well

Comment: [Edit] your post to tag that RDBMS.

Comment: The example you provided is doing the other way round. Any idea on how to do the above

Comment: Updated the question, with what I tried any suggestions on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    with t as (
     select ID, name, tag, tag_1, tag_2, tag_3, tag_4, location from table_one
     )
     select * from t
     unpivot (
     value for _tag_ in (tag,tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4)
     )
```

edit:
identified three issues with OP's sql:

1. the WITH clause does not contain the columns TAG_1 .. TAG_4 but they have been included in the UNPIVOT clause.

> ```
> with t as (
>  select ID, name, tag,location from table_one
>  )
> ```

2. the UNPIVOT clause is using an existing column TAG to collect the values of TAG_1 to TAG_4.

> ```
>  unpivot (
>  value for tag in (tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4
>  )
> ```

3. expected result set shows the value from TAG but not listed in the IN block.

> value for tag in (tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER 2008:

```
SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
TAG,
LOCATION
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
TAG_1,
LOCATION
FROM TABLE  
UNION
SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
TAG_2,
LOCATION
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
TAG_3,
LOCATION
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
TAG_4,
LOCATION
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: The OP said 4 minutes before your answer that they were using Oracle. (I'd expect this to work there too, but it should really be tested before posting.) Anyway, `TABLE` is not a good name for a table, since it's a reserved word.

Comment: I know this is a way to do it, with all the unions, but I have about 30+ columns, is there another way using pivot to do this.

Comment: So you should edit your post to make it clear that you want a more concise/reusable solution (rather than just one that does only just what you asked and no more)

Comment: Oracle only added support for CROSS APPLY in 12c. Also I fail to see how using that construct would make life any easier. Perhaps you could edit your answer to make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question correctly. You can do this using PIVOT in oracle. Try this. You can add more to the list in the PIVOT clause if required.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 10 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_1' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 10 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_2' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 10 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_3' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 10 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_4' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 10 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_5' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 20 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_2' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 20 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_4' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 20 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_6' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 30 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_1' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 30 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_3' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 30 AS id, 'test' AS name, 'abc_5' AS tag, 'china' AS location FROM DUAL)
     PIVOT (MAX (tag) AS tag FOR (tag) IN ('abc_1' AS t1, 'abc_2' AS t2, 'abc_3' AS t3, 'abc_4' AS t4, 'abc_5' AS t5, 'abc_6' AS t6))
```

ORDER BY id, name, location;

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test_pivot
(TID  number,
Tname  varchar2(10),
Tag_1  varchar2(10),
Tag_2  varchar2(10),
Tag_3   varchar2(10),
Tag_4    varchar2(10),
Tag_5    varchar2(10),
T_Location  varchar2(10)
);


insert into test_pivot(TID,
Tname,
Tag_1,
Tag_2,
Tag_3,
Tag_4,
Tag_5,
T_Location
)
values(10,'Test','ABC','PQR','TUV','LMN','XYZ','INDIA');


select * from test_pivot;

select *
from test_pivot
unpivot(value for tag in (Tag_1 as 'Tag_1',
Tag_2 as 'Tag_2',
Tag_3 as 'Tag_3',
Tag_4 as 'Tag_4',
Tag_5 as 'Tag_5')
)
```